# Nginx minikube ingress : 503 Server error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I am trying to use minikube to deploy a sample flask app. But getting 503 nginx error. Please note I am able to access the app using the Nodeport service config.

I checked with minikube IP which is mapped to local host and tried to access the app, but getting 503 error. Not sure if I missed anything. I enable the minikube addons for nginx.

Here are my files -

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flaskapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: flaskapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flaskapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flaskapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flaskapp
        image: <repo>/sample-flask-app:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
        - name: APPLICATION_SETTINGS
          value: prd_config.py
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: jfrog-secret
```

Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flaskapp-service
  labels:
    app: flaskapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: flaskapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: flaskapp-ingress
  labels:
    app: flaskapp
spec:
  defaultBackend:
      service:
        name: default-http-backend
        port:
          number: 80
  rules:
  - host: mydashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: flaskapp-service
            port: 
              number: 5000
```

Ingress status :

```
minikube kubectl -- get ingress flaskapp-ingress
NAME               CLASS   HOSTS             ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
flaskapp-ingress   nginx   mydashboard.com   localhost   80      18m
```

Cluster status:

```
minikube kubectl -- get all
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
pod/flaskapp-deployment-7f59f96fd5-j9mv9   1/1     Running   1 (103m ago)   15h

NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/flaskapp-deployment   ClusterIP   10.103.143.58   <none>        5000/TCP   34m
service/flaskapp-service      ClusterIP   10.111.242.99   <none>        5000/TCP   15h
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    35h

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/flaskapp-deployment   1/1     1            1           15h

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/flaskapp-deployment-7f59f96fd5   1         1         1       15h
```

Comment: Are you ysu using Windows? With which driver ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Well, maybe if you change the driver, because under Windows, Ingress doesn't work with Docker driver.
Follow this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gip-Q6AWpcY

Comment: okay I will try